# Is it possible to add two indexes of a string to a character to then convert that character to an int in c++?

Tags: c++, string, char, type-conversion, int

For example, I have a `string st="1234567"` and I want to add `st[0]` and `st[1]` to char ch so that `ch = 12`, and then to convert that to an int x so that `x = 12`.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve it like this:

```
int x = 10*(st[0]-'0') + (st[1]-'0');
```

This works because subtracting `'0'` from a `char` representing a number results in that actual number. So for instance `'5' - '0' == 5`.

---

> char ch so that ch = 12

That's not possible though. You can do `char ch = 12`, but that's not going to represent a `12`, that will most likely just result in something that might not be printable. In ASCII that would be a "form feed" and if you tried to print that, it could perhaps put a newline (or skip to the next page if your editor supports that). If you want a string to hold `"12"`, you can do it this way:

```
std::string twelve = st.substr(0, 2);
```

And from there a general way of converting to `int` would be

```
int x = std::stoi(twelve);
```

Comment: This helped. In particular, I was wondering more about saving it in a char but I didn't think that was possible. For some reason, stoi wasn't working but atof did. I'm not really sure why but I got it. Thanks for all your help!